# creating gridview dynamically with checkboxes inside it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a dynamic gridview and inside that gridview, I want to bind that gridview with a listbox items. I want first two columns of the gridview as checkboxes and the 
third item as item from the listbox. I want something like this

```
foreach (ListItem item in Listbox1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        Listbox2.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Text, item.Value));
    }
}

GridView gridview1 = new GridView();
foreach(ListItem item in Listbox2.Items)
{
    CheckBoxField chk = new CheckBoxField();

    chk.HeaderText = "Test1";

    gridview1.Columns.Add(chk);

    CheckBoxField chk2 = new CheckBoxField();

    chk.HeaderText = "Test2";

    gridview1.Columns.Add(chk);

    // another columns that displays the item from the list box
    // another column that displays the value of the item of the listbox, but the column is hidden.
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You simply add an event handler for the on databound event for the GridView which means you can access the current row, columns and the data for that row and then add the controls to that row with whatever options (text, checked, disabled, etc) you need.